# MySQL Installation Failed - Can't Create Folder

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.6.12 on my MacBook Pro running OS 10.7.5.
I ran the install package and received an "install failed" message:

```
The Installer can't create the folder /var/folders/ym/fjmt27ys02l0yyhqjkfkd9100000gn/T//Install.747XBTKTG
```

I've tried creating this directory myself, but have been unsuccessful.  The "T" folder has a little red symbol on it, and I can't modify it, even with sudo as an admin.

Have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: This folder is a temporary one. i saw this on support.apple.
Back up all data, then enter the following command in the same way as before:

 

sudo chown -R $UID $TMPDIR..

 

You'll be prompted for your login password, which won't be displayed when you type it. You may get a one-time warning not to screw up. If you don’t have a login password, you’ll need to set one before you can run the command.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4015838?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Please check the entire post there.

Comment: Thank you! After running this command, MySQL installed flawlessly.

Comment: Ohh, nice... i use MAMP because i need PHP. but it must work now. anything just ask